# swagger-ui: Unknown response type

Tags: javascript, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I am attempting to set up the swagger ui for an existing REST api (which I cannot change).

For most end-points this works fine, but there is one endpoint that returns JSON, and the swagger UI (when doing try-it-out) fails to parse the response body. The message looks like:

```
Response body: Unknown response type
Response headers
  content-type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
```

When running the curl command manually, there is data returned though. The returned data looks like:

```
{"A B":["C"],"D":["E"]}
```

The response header is:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2018 14:18:46 GMT
Server: Jetty(9.2.1.v20140609)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
```

I've attempted various things in the OpenAPI specification (3.0), but nothing seems to work. Currently have,

```
  openapi: "3.0.0"
  ...
  responses:
    200:
      description: OK
      content:
        application/javascript:
          schema:
            type: string
```

Am I missing something here? Note that I cannot change the REST API itself, so have no control over the response type (application/javascript here). As mentioned before, everything works fine if I do this for an endpoint that just returns text/plain.

Happy to provide more details if required. The REST API itself is proprietary and in-house, so can't show too much, unfortunately.

Thanks,
-Joris.

Comment: What browser and [Swagger UI version](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/version-detection.md) are you using? Also, you mention OpenAPI 3.0 but the syntax (`produces` etc.) is 2.0 - is your definition `swagger: '2.0'` or `openapi: 3.0.0`?

Comment: The definition is openapi: 3.0.0. I have probably mixed and matched the different styles in my attempts to get something to work. I'll look up the correct 3.0 syntax and see if that helps. I am using swagger-ui version 3.13.2 in Chrome 65.0.

Comment: I have now updated the question with what I believe is the proper OpenAPI 3.0 syntax. The behaviour in swagger-ui is the same, though.

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue in the [Swagger UI repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues).

Comment: Thanks. In case anyone else ends up here: I created https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4406